# Python Generate TOTP Counter Value (Platform Independent)

Tags: python, totp

I am trying to create a TOTP generator. This needs a 'counter value' which uses the following formula:
Calculating counter value

[image: CT = (T - T0)/TX]

```
CT  Count of the number of durations TX between T0 and T
T   Current time or Unix time
T0  some epoch (eg. Unix epoch is 0)
TX  length of one time duration (eg 30 seconds)
```

My code is:

```
from datetime import datetime
import math

window = 60
epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
timenow = datetime.now()

timekey = math.floor((timenow - epoch).total_seconds() / window)

print(timekey)
```

However, this results in slightly different values when running on my local linux machine, vs tio.run (not sure what OS), I don't have a windows or macOS machine handy to test.

My machine: `26654068`
TIO: `26654008`

Why is my code not producing the same value? Do one of the datetime functions not do what I was expecting?

Comment: That looks like a timezone difference.  Try `.utcnow()` instead of `.now()`.

Comment: That works  Thanks!